# Angular 2 get dynamic value between components

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, pagination, angular2-components

I am using [table plugin](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/blob/development/components/table/ng-table.component.ts) and [pagination plugin](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/pagination/pagination.component.ts). My target is to detect current page number from pagination component and to add it in table component. How is that possible? Already tried:

```
import { PaginationComponent } from '../+pagination/pagination.component';
@Component({
 ...
  providers: [PaginationComponent]
})
public currPage: number;
public constructor(private pagin: PaginationComponent) {
    this.currPage = this.pagin.page;
}
```

which works, but did not detect any changes. What must I change to make it detect changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using it :

```
<pagination (pageChanged)="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

Inside the class that uses above :

```
export class SomethingThatUsesPagination{
    pageChanged($event){
        this.pageService.onChanged$.emit($event);
    }
}
```

and the create a service and inject it in both components

```
@Injectable()
export class PageService{
   public onChanged$ = new EventEmitter();
}
```

and then inside the other component that needs to know about pagination stuff :

```
export class OtherComponent{
    constructpr(public pageService: PageService){
        pageService.onChanged$.subscribe(($event) => {
            console.log('$event',$event);
        });
    }
}
```

this is two component are communicating through a service.

Comment: Can I set two parameters? Let say two separate strings? Do I need two subjects and two Observables?